# Usage of chroot after pivot_root

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, mount

From what I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong) the semantics of these commands is:

1. Every process has a root filesystem (i.e. a filesystem mounted on `/`).
2. Child processes inherit the root filesystem of their parents.
3. `chroot` starts a new process with a new root filesystem (instead of inheriting from parent process).
4. `pivot_root` changes the root filesystem of the present process while keeping the old root accessible.

Now consider the following example (from linux manual of `pivot_root`)

```
mount /dev/hda1 /new-root
cd /new-root
pivot_root . old-root
exec chroot . sh <dev/console >dev/console 2>&1
umount /old-root
```

Why is `chroot` necessary? It is called from a directory which is already the root (because of the previous `pivot_root`). Shouldn't

`sh <dev/console >dev/console 2>&1`

be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`man pivot_root`](https://manpages.debian.org/util-linux/pivot_root.8) tells:

> Note that `exec chroot` changes the running executable, which is necessary if the old root directory should be unmounted afterwards.

Same goes for a few other resources as mentioned afterward.

Without *chroot* to the newer filesystem the `umount` command will fail with EBUSY, because the shell's process is still keeping a resource usage in the former filesystem: the shell's binary file itself (and possible associated libraries). The `exec chroot` will, in addition to the actual *chroot* action, replace the shell with a different shell which is present on the newer filesystem, thus freeing the former one and allowing to unmount it.

UPDATE: Why isn't `exec` (without `chroot`) sufficient?

The man page also tells:

> Note that, **depending on the implementation of `pivot_root`, root and cwd
> of the caller may or may not change.** The following is a sequence for
> invoking pivot_root that works in either case, assuming that
> `pivot_root` and `chroot` are in the current `PATH`:
>
> ```
> cd new_root
> pivot_root . put_old
> exec chroot . command
> ```

Here `root` means the new `/` after the *pivot_root*. So not using `exec chroot` leads to undefined behaviour, while using it will work for all implementations.

For example (but I didn't check), it might depend on the kernel version or the exact syscalls and their order made in the command [`pivot_root(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/util-linux/pivot_root.8) beside [pivot_root(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/pivot_root.2), depending on its specific version.

Comment: I understand, but shouldn't `exec sh ...` work the same, even without `chroot`?

Comment: I added an update about this question.